# Is there a way to fixe that error without using end=" "

Tags: python, string

that's my code :

```
           while (i < a):
             p = string[i]
             i = i + 1
             print(p)
```

that's the result :

A
M
O
R
T
I
S
S
E
M
E
N
T

T
A
B
L
I
E
R
,

A

G
A
U
C
H
E
None

it's solved when i print it that way but i need to stock it and reuse it  :

print(p, end=" ")

AMORTISSEMENT TABLIER, A GAUCHENone

Comment: Drop the `while` loop and just do `print(' '.join(string))`

Comment: i have that text and i ve to extract the name of the element , so i cant drop the while loop  
i should limit the extraction 
20A 211 682 29 28AMORTISSEMENT TABLIER, A GAUCHECode: (802/803/804/804/805/806)

Comment: the a in while (i<a) is the position of "Code" where i should stop the extraction of the name